# Нужна ли запятая перед предлогом?

Tags: запятые

В предложении "В старой квартире(,) в моей комнате мы не будем делать ремонт".
Одни мне говорят, что это обстоятельство и оно не отделяется запятыми. Другие говорят, что надо двумя запятыми выделить "в моей комнате" или взять "в моей комнате в скобки". Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1):

*В старой квартире, **в моей комнате**, мы не будем делать ремонт.*

Обособленное **уточняющее** обстоятельство со значение сужения места.

**Однородные** отношения (одна запятая) по смыслу невозможны, а **неоднородные** отношения (без  запятых) не подходят для структуры этого предложения.

Сравнить: *В моей комнате в старой квартире // мы  не будем делать ремонт.*